# \newpage not working in article class

Tags: packages, line-breaking, article

I'm having an error with my code but i don't know why. Please help me with this:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[font=small, labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=black,
    filecolor=magenta,      
    urlcolor=blue,
}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage{apacite}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\newcommand{\HRule}[1]{\rule{\linewidth}{#1}}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\setlength\headheight{15pt}
\fancyhead[L]{\chaptername \ \thechapter} 
\fancyhead[R]{Universidad Pontificia Bolivariana}
\fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}

\begin{document}

\title{ \LARGE \textbf{Desarrollo de una herramienta para la programación de horarios en una institución educativa con restricciones de disponibilidad de docentes mediante modelación matemática por programación lineal entera mixta.} %para que quede encerrado en las líneas
        \vspace{5\baselineskip}}

\author{ Autor: Yelky Castro Jimenez. \\ 
        Asesor: MSc. Victor Noble Ramos. 

    \vspace{5\baselineskip}
    \normalsize Universidad Pontificia Bolivariana \\
    Facultad de Ingenierías y Arquitectura\\
    Programa de Ingeniería Industrial
}

\maketitle

\newpage

\input{intro}

\end{document}
```

Comment: If I add `\documentclass{article}`, I get an error due to `\thechapter` and two pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. you have a blank line (which is a paragraph end mark) in `\author`; remove it.
2. `article` class has no chapters! Use `book` or `report` if you want chapters.